# Userscript Looping On Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I've hacked this together from a few examples. The expected behavior is to append the string "?foo" to the end of urls for barsite.com, then terminate.

The actual behavior is it appends to the URL, then endlessly refreshes the page and appends the string. I don't know enough about scripting/js to figure out why this is behaving like a loop.

I'm not sure if my regexp is the culprit, or something in the body of the statement.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Barfoo Hack
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Add ?foo to barsite.com urls
// @author       DC
// @match        *://*.barsite.com/*
// @run-at       document-start
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var oldUrlPath = window.location.pathname;

if ( ! /\?foo/.test (oldUrlPath) ) {
    var newURL = window.location.protocol + "//" +
    window.location.host + oldUrlPath + "?foo" +
    window.location.search +
    window.location.hash;
    window.location.replace (newURL);
}
```

Comment: Your code says, everytime you go to barsite.com, refresh with an extra foo argument. So you go to barsite.com, you get redirected to barsite.com with a foo; but now you arrive at barsite.com again, the script triggers again, and it redirects you to barsite.com. Wait, you're at barsite.com again; you better get another foo in there, let's redirect again... The loop is not in the script; the loop is the result of the script re-triggering itself by its behaviour.

Comment: Oh, you mean why your regexp doesn't prevent it? Because `?foo` is in `window.location.search`, not in `window.location.pathname` that you're testing.

Comment: @Amadan You're saying that I should test in `window.location.search` instead of `window.location.pathname` ?

Comment: Affirmative....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Amadan, the solution is to test in `window.location.search` instead of `window.location.pathname`

The updated example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Barfoo Hack
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Add ?foo to barsite.com urls
// @author       DC
// @match        *://*.barsite.com/*
// @run-at       document-start
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var oldUrlPath = window.location.pathname;
var testPath = window.location.search;

if ( ! /\?foo/.test (testPath) ) {
    var newURL = window.location.protocol + "//" +
    window.location.host + oldUrlPath + "?foo" +
    window.location.search +
    window.location.hash;
    window.location.replace (newURL);
}
```